# Dynamic condition in IF statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to make condition of `if` statement dynamically in javascript,

check my code

```
var t = ['b','a']
if(t[0] !== 'a' && t[1] !== 'a'){console.log('remaining element')}
```

here t might be vary at any time say `t = ['b','a','c']` then I need to write if condition like this

```
if(t[0] !== 'a' && t[1] !== 'a' && t[2] !== 'a'){console.log('remaining element')}
```

How can I rewirte this code efficiently?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) like this

```
if (t.every(function(currentElement) { return currentElement !== "a"; })) {
    console.log('remaining element');
}
```

This works with arbitrary number of elements.

On older environments which do not support `Array.prototype.every`, you can use the plain for loop version

```
var flag = true;
for (var i = 0 ; i < t.length; i += 1) {
    if (t[i] === "a") {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (flag) {
    console.log('remaining element');
}
```

Comment: Note that older IE versions (8 and below) do not support `Array.prototype.every`.